# How the formula for mean energy of quantum harmonic oscillator is derived?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I mean this formula:

$$\varepsilon ={\frac {h\nu }{2}}+{\frac {h\nu }{e^{h\nu /kT}-1}}$$

Is there full derivation somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Remember the partition function is
$$Z = \sum_E e^{-\beta E}$$
But $E=\hbar \omega (n+\frac12)$ so
$$Z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty  (e^{-\beta \hbar \omega\cdot \frac12 }\cdot e^{-\beta \hbar \omega\cdot n })=e^{-\beta \frac{\hbar \omega}{2}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty   (e^{-\beta \hbar \omega })^n = e^{-\beta \frac{\hbar \omega}{2}}\cdot \frac{1}{1-e^{-\beta \hbar \omega}}$$
(The sum is determined by using the sum of an infinite geometric series)

Now just use $\langle E\rangle = \sum E\cdot e^{-\beta E}  /Z$ (again use wisely the sum of an infinite series) or any other formula from statistical mechanics (deriving the partition function by beta and taking a Log...) and you'll get your answer